# Trying to detect if a key is press down

Tags: java

I have a program that I would like to exit when a key is press down.  Right now it is in a endless do while loop.  I'm assuming I would have to detect the key down within the while.

code

```
do { 
  prices=mBitTrex.GetCurSales();
  prices.display();

  try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 } while(true);
      //  System.out.println(cJason.GetString(reply, "\"Bid\":",  ",") );

}
```

Comment: Under what frame work? Swing, AWT, SWT, GWT ... ?

Comment: Read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

Comment: Or is this a console program? If so, you're going to need a special console.

Comment: @MarsAtomic: if his is a Swing program, he's got more problems than a KeyListener will solve, including that `Thread.sleep(...)`. We also try to avoid use of KeyListeners in general in favor of Key Bindings.

Comment: Voting to close question for being unclear. Hopefully he will correct this situation soon.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to to exit the program by pressing maybe the "escape" button
 then try implementing this code

```
          private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
  if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
 {
     System.exit(0);
 }
 }
```

when you press the escape button, the program should close